# summing value by date, two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in tab1 and tab2, goal is sum values all occurrences of value of given id in tab2 and display them next to date;

my first tab1 looks

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| A  |
| B  |
| C  |
| D  |
+----+
```

and my second tab2 looks:

```
  +----+-----+-------+------------+
| in | out | value |    date    |
+----+-----+-------+------------+
| A  |     |    10 | 2019-05-06 |
| A  |     |   100 | 2019-05-11 |
| D  | C   |   100 | 2019-06-11 |
|    | A   |    50 | 2019-07-15 |
| C  |     |    11 | 2019-07-28 |
+----+-----+-------+------------+
```

and for example for id A i wanna get:

```
+-----+------------+
| sum |    date    |
+-----+------------+
|  10 | 2019-05-06 |
| 110 | 2019-05-11 |
|  60 | 2019-07-15 |
+-----+------------+
```

any idea?i can only sum until given date

Comment: Why `60` in the 3d row?

Comment: the output shown seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: it's like bank account transfer money to (in) account and from (out) account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIth conditional summing of the column value:

```
select
  (
    select sum(
      case when "in" = 'A' then 1 else - 1 end * value
    ) 
    from tab2 
    where 'A' in ("in", out) and 
    date <= t2.date
  ) sum, 
  date
from tab2 t2
where 'A' in (t2."in", t2.out)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7LRUJcthty6NGYJyWAkhxo/0).
Results:

```
| sum | date       |
| --- |----------- |
| 10  | 2019-05-06 |
| 110 | 2019-05-11 |
| 60  | 2019-07-15 |
```

Comment: and do you have idea how to change it when i want sth like this but for all possible id, not for one? i've triead with id from tab1 bud didnt get it

Comment: Give me a few mins to try something.

Answer (score 0):

use window function `sum()`

```
 select sum(value)over(partition by "in" order by date ) as s,date
 from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative sum:

```
select date, value,
       sum(value) over (partition by coalesce(in, out)
                        order by (case when "in" is not null then value else - value end)
                       ) as value_sum
from tab2 t
where coalesce("in", "out") = 'A'
order by date;
```

You can simplify using a subquery or lateral join:

```
select t.date, v.signed_value,
       sum(value) over (partition by v.id
                        order by v.signed_value
                       ) as value_sum
from tab2 t cross join lateral
     (values (coalesce("in", "out"),
              (case when "in" is not null then value else - value end)
             )
     ) v(id, signed_value
where v.id = 'A'
order by t.date;
```

EDIT:

If both in and out can be filled in:

```
select date, value,
       sum(value) over (partition by coalesce(in, out)
                        order by (case when "in" is not null then value else - value end)
                       ) as value_sum
from tab2 t
where coalesce("in", "out") = 'A'
order by date;
```

You can simplify using a subquery or lateral join:

```
select t.date, v.signed_value,
       sum(value) over (partition by v.id
                        order by v.signed_value
                       ) as value_sum
from tab2 t cross join lateral
     (values ("in", value), ("out", -value)),
     ) v(id, signed_value
where v.id = 'A'
order by t.date;
```

Comment: it's giving me wrong ans, (suming all values?) and ofc i did't mention but both column in and out could by filled( i ve edited problem)

Comment: @cvzx . . . I adjusted the answer.  It is actually simpler.